# Testing a Thymeleaf custom dialect with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, thymeleaf

I recently wrote a custom dialect for Thymeleaf along with a custom processor to process some custom tags and replace them with different ones in some cases, but I'm having issues writing tests for the processor:

The `AbstractProcessor` class requires to override the

```
protected ProcessorResult doProcess(Arguments arguments, ProcessorMatchingContext processorMatchingContext, Node node)
```

method, which is the one I need to test.

Since my processor involves getting variables from the `arguments` parameter, I tried mocking it; however, the `Arguments`, `ProcessorMatchingContext`and `Node` classes are all declared final, which means that they cannot be mocked by Mockito.

I don't really want to instantiate an actual `Arguments` object, since it depends on 5 other objects that cannot be mocked and I would end up writing tons of code to test just one line in my processor.

Any ideas for a possible testing strategy?

Comment: PowerMock can mock final classes: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockFinal , as well as static methods, etc.

Comment: I know, but it's quite a large project and I don't want to introduce PowerMock just for this case

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would help or not, but you can instantiate an actual (non-mock) Arguments without all of the 5 other dependent classes, using [Objenesis](http://objenesis.org/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `mockito.when().thenReturn()`
If your **parameters** are doing any sort of calls you need to mock that after that you can easily test your **method**.